# php checking whether dynamically generated variables are declared or not

Tags: php, regex, associative-array

I have array like

```
array(
    "v"=>1,
    "u"=>8,
    "v1"=>45,
    "v123"=>12
);
```

In my program i need to check whether the array contains an element whose key starts with v followed by numbers.My array is very large ,so that I do not prefer iteration.Is there any other efficient way to do this.I expect something like isset(arr[regex]);

Comment: [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) seems to be what you need (with the proper function).

Comment: *Something* has to iterate through it, direct key access is only possible for known keys. You can dress that iteration up in various ways, but it's inevitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_filter (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

first creat a callback function:

```
function getKeys($n){
 return preg_match('/^v[0-9]+$/', $n);
}
```

Then run the array_filter:

```
$arr = array(
    "v"=>1,
    "u"=>8,
    "v1"=>45,
    "v123"=>12
);

$newArr = array_filter(array_keys($arr), "getKeys");
```

You can see the result with the right array_keys:

```
print_r($newArr);
```

If you have a result this statement should be true:

```
echo count($newArr) > 0;
```

Comment: Doesn't do what you think. Please test your code before posting.

Comment: You are very right! I didn't post my tested version. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

A dirty hack that might work would be to:

1. Use `array_keys()` to get all the keys
2. Implode the resulting array keys
3. Perform a REGEX on that resulting string.

```php
$data   = array(
    "v"     =>1,
    "u"     =>8,
    "v1"    =>45,
    "v123"  =>12
);

$keys   = array_keys($data);

$key_string = implode(',', $keys);

$matches    = array();
preg_match('/^v[0-9]{0,}$/', $key_string, $matches);
```

OR, shortened

```
$matches    = array();
preg_match('/^v[0-9]{0,}$/', implode(',', array_keys($data)), $matches);
```

I'm not sure how much of a performance hit you will get by using `array_keys` & `implode`, but it should work for you.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to define `$matches` before `preg_match`. The pass by reference of the function actually automatically creates it when you pass it. It's a little language quirk.

Comment: your regex should be '/^v[0-9]{0,}$/' instead of '^v[0-9]{0,}$'

Comment: @arnoudhgz thanks for catching that, nothing worse than an incorrect regex floating around.

Comment: @Leigh so if I have a variable with the name `$matches`, will `preg_match()` override that variable?

Comment: @Patrick It will indeed. If the variable exists it will be overwritten (the function clears the array as one of its internal steps), if it doesn't exist it is created by the meer fact of passing it to the function, this is due to the fact the argument is defined as `&$matches` (pass by reference).

Comment: @Leigh that could be a very difficult 'bug' to track down if I ever came across it in the wild.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Patrick It's not a bug, I was just trying to explain why it's not needed. I hope I didn't create a misunderstanding. `$matches` is cleared explicitly by `preg_match*`, not by the fact it is passed by reference. I was trying to get at the fact the reference would create variables that had not been explicitly created. Demo: http://ideone.com/9XrQP

Comment: @Leigh sorry, I meant 'bug' as in something that would confuse a person and they would think it's a bug when in reality it is the correct functionality